# Multiple Galleries using Galleria.js with Flickr and JSON

Tags: jquery, json, flickr, galleria

Is there anyway of getting this galleria.js example to work with JSON and Flickr?
http://goo.gl/Fk3h5

Reason being, I have 500 Flickr photos in a set and using Galleria's supplied Flickr plugin, it takes forever to load or crashes the browser. JSON method seems ideal.

I've already come across this tutorial http://goo.gl/3L5Nn but it only covers one photoset with JSON.

I can't seem to figure out how to tie it all together. Help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) to separate out the content, then pull in the [different galleries when the tabs are clicked](http://www.cincoranch.com/Photos-Videos/Photo-Gallery). I recently did this with a [Umbraco CMS](http://umbraco.com/) backend to host the images, but would be the same for flickr.

Comment: try to include some example code since if the links go dead your answer does not have enough content to stand on its own.